# Is there a way to tell if the game is paused without check the Time.timeScale?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
var t = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Main Menu");
    
if (pauseGameOnToggle && t.name != "Main Menu")
{
        Time.timeScale = isActive ? 0 : 1;
}
```

this is working fine but, in my project, the Main Menu scene name is indeed Main Menu it doesn't mean in everyone else project/s there is a Main Menu scene by that name at all.

if I will check like this:

```
var t = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Main Menu");
    
if (pauseGameOnToggle && Time.timeScale != 0)
{
        Time.timeScale = isActive ? 0 : 1;
}
```

then it will pause the game but then will never continue.

the reason I want to make this checking is because when I press the escape key and loading the main menu scene the game is already pausing, and I don't want to pause it again.

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.BackQuote))
        {
            justToggled = true; // Mark that we've just toggled to prevent immediate input
            ToggleInputField();
            StartCoroutine(PreventImmediateBackquoteInput());
        }
        else if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.KeypadEnter)) && inputField.gameObject.activeSelf)
        {
            AddNewLine();
        }
    
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

and

```
    private void ToggleInputField()
    {
        bool isActive = !inputField.gameObject.activeSelf;
        inputField.gameObject.SetActive(isActive);
    
        var t = SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Main Menu");
    
        if (pauseGameOnToggle && Time.timeScale != 0) //t.name != "Main Menu")
        {
            Time.timeScale = isActive ? 0 : 1;
        }
    
        if (isActive)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DelayedActivateInputField());
            // Remove the backquote if it was added when toggling the field off
            inputField.text = RemoveBackquote(inputField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            // Save the notes when toggling the field off without the backquote
            if (saveToFile)
            {
                SaveToFile(RemoveBackquote(inputField.text));
            }
        }
    }
```

and because this script is at another scene without dontdestroyonload when I toggle on/off the InputField ui I don't want to pause the game again if the game is already paused for any reason.

so, the checking logic by checking for the Main Menu name if the scene is loaded is working fine in my case but I want to make something more global/generic to check it and not only for my current project.

Comment: why not simply have a `static bool isPaused;` somewhere and based on that set `Time.timeScale = isPaused ? 0 : 1;` ... and then simply set the bool accordingly?